# Qt Designer and stylesheets

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, stylesheet, qt-designer

I have derived a `CalibrationWindow` from `QWidget`, and I have a vector of `CalibrationWindow*`. Now, I'm trying to change the background color in the Designer with the following stylesheet:

```
#calibrationWindow
{
    background : rgb(220, 220, 220);
}
```

(The Qt object name is `calibrationWindow`). In the Designer, it looks as intended, but when I run the program, zilch. No effect whatsoever. I also tried using `CalibrationWindow` instead of `#calibrationWindow`, to no avail. I even put `QWidget`, but it affects the child widgets and not the parent, as I want.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Certain properties need to be set in QMainWindow or QApplication prior to creating QMainWindow to work.  Doesn't appear to be your specific problem, but here for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was not overriding the `paintEvent()` function... It's compulsory when subclassing from `QWidget`.